# Функция которая принимает массив элементов и другую функцию

Tags: javascript, функции

Начал изучать JS и попалось задание!
Нужно написать функцию которая принимает массив элементов и функцию как параметр.
Пробежаться по этим элементам и передать в другую функцию которая умеет принимать элемент и возвращать true либо false. Если результат === true удалить это элемент!
Вот мой код.

```
function predicat(tagName) {
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    if (el.className === 'hey') {
        console.log(el.className);
        return true;
    }

}


function removeElementIfConditionsTrue(arr, callback) {
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName(arr);
    for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        callback(el);
        if (el.className === true) {
           el.remove();
        }
    }

}
var elements = ['input', 'div', 'textarea'];
removeElementIfConditionsTrue(elements, predicat);
```

Ребят помогите, третий день сижу, не хочу бросать это задание. Пересмотрел кучу роликов, но так нечего и не понял!Спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте, для начала, сделать на каком-то одном типе элемента. Важно понять, что и в какую функцию вы передаёте. Как минимум, Вам нужно передавать не всю коллекцию, а i-тый элемент из цикла ```el[i]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум, Вам нужно передавать не всю коллекцию, а i-тый элемент из цикла el[i]

```js
let predicat = (el, word) => el === word
 
function removeElementIfConditionsTrue(arr, callback,word) {
    let el = document.querySelectorAll(arr);
    for(let i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
if(callback(el[i].className, word))  {
document.querySelector(`.${el[i].className}`).remove();
} 
}
}
let arr = ['div', 'input', 'textarea']
removeElementIfConditionsTrue(arr, predicat, "hey");
```

```html
<div class="block">block</div>
<div class="hey">hey</div>
<div class="block">block</div>
<div class="block">block</div>
<div class="block">block</div>
<div class="error">error</div>
<input class="inp" type="text">
<input class="hey" type="text" placeholder = 'hey'>

<textarea class="area" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: если помог, отметьте галочку, чтобы закрыть вопрос